# regex lazy before capturing group

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation

Using the following regex

```
<w:p.*?\$\{test\}.*?\/w:p>
```

I'm trying to match the first

```
<w:p>
```

before the "${test}" and the first

```
</w:p>
```

after. The after worked just fine, using the ? quantifier, but it refuses to stop at the first

```
<w:body><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00271ADB"/><w:p w:rsidR="00C15291"><w:pPr><w:p w:rsidR="0093632F" w:rsidRDefault="0093632F"><w:pPr><w:rPr></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:br/><w:t>${test}</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body>
```

This is what I expected the result to be:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0093632F" w:rsidRDefault="0093632F"><w:pPr><w:rPr></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:br/><w:t>${test}</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

but instead this is what being returned

```
<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00271ADB"/><w:p w:rsidR="00C15291"><w:pPr><w:p w:rsidR="0093632F" w:rsidRDefault="0093632F"><w:pPr><w:rPr></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:br/><w:t>${test}</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

This is the result in the editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ri4C.png

And this is the result I'm expecting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W87K9.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to change the first `.*?` into a repeated group with a negative lookahead. You should also notice that I added a `\s` after `<w:p`, this is so `<w:pPr` doesn't get matched.  If you have some `<w:p>` instances, you may need to change this to `<w:p(?:\s|>)`.

```
<w:p\s(?:(?!<w:p\s).)*?\$\{test\}.*?\/w:p>
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kK8iY8)

---

RegEx matches from left to right, so there is no real way to say "lazy before".  Instead of `.*?` I used `(?:(?!<w:p\s).)*?`.  Lets break that down:

```
(?:         (?# begin non-capturing group for grouping/repetition)
  (?!       (?# begin negative lookahead)
    <w:p\s  (?# no <w:p ahead)
  )         (?# end negative lookahead)
  .         (?# match any character)
)*?         (?# lazy repetition)
```

How this works is as soon as we match `<w:p\s`, we enter the non-capturing/repeated group.  It does a zero-length assertion to make sure `<w:p\s` doesn't exist ahead of that point, and then matches a character.  This lazily repeats until we hit `${test}`.  If the expression sees a `<w:p\s` in the lookahead, it will fail..and a new match will start back up, matching that `<w:p\s` in the beginning (and starting to do more lookaheads).

Comment: Very clever! Thank you Sam for the explanation as well :)

Comment: Nice detailed answer delving into laziness. :) +1